# how to add a YouTube link in option menu?

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink

Does someone know how to add a YouTube link in this code?
So that if you press an option that Python send you to the YouTube page.

This is the code:

```
#IMPORT
import tkinter
import webbrowser
#END IMPORT
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("welcome to this page")
root.geometry('700x500')

option_list = ["meme", "meme", "meme", "meme"]

value_inside = tkinter.StringVar(root)

value_inside.set("select an Option: ")

question_menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(root, value_inside, *option_list)
question_menu.pack()

def print_answers():
    print("Select Option: {}".format(value_inside.get()))
    return None 

submit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text='submit', command=print_answers)
submit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: where exactly is the issue? you are almost there, you just need to `webbrowser.open` the value of `value_inside`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching on Stack Overflow, I finally figured this out: you need to pass `print_answers` to a `command` keyword argument when creating the `OptionMenu`. This calls `print_answers` every time a user selects an option from the menu.

To open the url, simply use `webbrowser.open()`. Here is what `print_answer()` would look like:

```py
def print_answer(selected_option):
    webbrowser.open(value_inside.get())
```

(We will talk more about the `selected_option` argument at the end of the answer)

The complete code:

```py
#IMPORT
import tkinter
import webbrowser
#END IMPORT
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("welcome to this page")
root.geometry('700x500')

option_list = ["meme", "meme", "meme", "meme"]

value_inside = tkinter.StringVar(root)
value_inside.set("select an Option: ")

def print_answers(selected_option):
    webbrowser.open(value_inside.get())

question_menu = tkinter.OptionMenu(root, value_inside, *option_list, command=print_answers)
question_menu.pack()

submit_button = tkinter.Button(root, text='submit', command=print_answers)
submit_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Simply passing `print_answers` to the `command` argument calls it whenever an option is selected. Wish I had known this before!

An alternative to using the `value_inside` variable: the `OptionMenu` already passes the selected item as an argument to its command function (this is the `selected_option` argument I mentioned before; you can use anything in place of `selected_option`, since it's a positional argument). So, you could forget completely about `value_inside` and do this:

```py
def print_answer(selected_option):
    webbrowser.open(selected_option)
```